# auto_html gem not loading in a rails 3 app (other gems works !)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

```
Rails version: 3.0.3
Ruby: 1.9.2pre
```

In a running app, I'm putting the auto_html(https://github.com/dejan/auto_html) in gemfile, then ran bundle install ok.

but none methods from auto_html seems to work.

rails server load normally, but auto_html method, and auto_html_for doesn`t work
always get errors like:

```
undefined method `auto_html' for #<#<Class:0x00000102c63330>:0x00000102c60ae0>
```

I know is a loading problem, but I am not getting any error, and I use many others gems.

any clue?

Comment: Please show us how you're trying to call this method.

Comment: Ryan,
I just follow up what is here:
https://github.com/dejan/auto_html

On a erb template, just:
   
    <%= auto_html(field) %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might have found out, but this :

```
include AutoHtml
```

has to be added somewhere

Comment: When ```AutoHtml``` included the ```NameError: uninitialized constant ArticleHelper::AutoHtml``` error appear

Comment: I finally got rid of this as it tends to be extremely unstable (besides the fact that it sounds buggy for many)

Answer (score 0):

maybe the gemfile isn't named like the library? bcrypt as an example has to be defined in Gemfile like:

```
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', :require => "bcrypt"
```

Comment: No, this is not it. See: https://github.com/dejan/auto_html/blob/master/lib/auto_html.rb

Answer (score 0):

This should probably be done in the lib itself, but currently to use it like that (auto_html method in the template) you'd have to include AutoHtml module in ApplicationHelper.